# Liquibase different behavior when using CLI and Maven

Tags: postgresql, maven, liquibase

I am integrating Liquibase in existing project. I used CLI to generate the change logs from the database and to execute *changeLogSync*. I verified that the *databasechangelog* table contains the data from the generated logs.

When I try to update the database from the generated change log in CLI:

```
liquibase --changeLogFile=changeLog.xml --url="jdbc:postgresql://database_server:port/database --defaultSchemaName=public update
```

it results in `Liquibase Update Successful`.

When I try to do the same inMaven it fails: `Failed to execute goal org.liquibase ... Error setting up or running Liquibase: Migaration failed for change set ... Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaException: ERROR: relation already exists.`

Note that I have not modified the *changeLog.xml* file and I have executed *changeLogSync*, so the update is expected to do nothing but when using Maven it tries to create all the relations.

The Maven config has the following structure:

```
<configuration>
  <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
  <propertyFile>liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
  <defaultSchemaName>public</defaultSchemaName>
</configuration>
<executions>
  <execution>
  <id>update</id>
  <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
  <goals>
    <goal>updateSQL</goal>
    <goal>update</goal>
  </goals>
  </execution>
</executions>
```

and the *liquibase.properties* file contains the rest of the parameters which are the same as those in the CLI command.

liquibase version: 3.4.1
postgresql version: 9.4-1201-jdbc41

I am aware that I can use preconditions in the *changeLog.xml* to prevent creating a table that exists but I think designwise its better to fix the Maven config.

Why is there a difference between CLI and Maven executions? I would also appreciate any suggestion on how to resolve such issues with Maven/Liquibase (debugging approach).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be caused by different "working directories". Depending on the environment Liquibase resolves the filename of the changelog differently. As the filename is part of the unique key in the table `databasechangelog` Liquibase might think a specific changeSet has not yet been executed.

If you check the `filename` column in `databasechangelog` you probably see different values, depending on the environment from which you ran the change log.

We resolved this by adding the attribute `logicaFilePath` to the `changeLog` tag for each XML file. The value was the plain filename without any directories in it.

Something like:

```
<databaseChangeLog 
     xmlns="...." 
     xmlns:xsi="..." 
     xsi:schemaLocation="...."
     logicalFilePath="changelog_v1.xml">
```

Comment: Instead of specifying the logicalFilePath you can ensure that the classpath you are using in the command line matches the maven classpath. But logicalFilepath ensures they are they seen as the same.

Comment: @NathanVoxland: thanks for the information, but how would I do that?

Comment: Command line liquibase has a -classpath attribute. Make sure that is set to include the same classpath root(s) that contain changelog files as Maven is using.